# Laravel customer support chat with third party Pusher

Tags: laravel, vue.js, websocket, pusher

I am trying to make Customer **Support chart** over the `laravel` and `Pusher` but in my console, there're some error. I am unable to understand it.

here is console:
[image]

And,

[image]

This is what i have in `Js` **file**

```js
window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: process.env.d8649589aa930d275ffe,
    cluster: process.env.ap2,
    encrypted: true
});
```

Comment: Kindly comment here if you **need more information** related this QUESTION?

Comment: what have you done at lavel side so far ?

Comment: Add text data as text, not images. You can't search text in images.

Comment: Are you using Laravel Echo? If so, can you add the js code to your question.

Comment: actually i just have pusher `connection issue`. @RossWilson

Comment: Ah fair enough. Can you add your js code?

Comment: I have added `.js` code in question. @RossWilson

Comment: How come you're requiring `pusher-js` but using `Echo`?

Comment: I am using this `package` with pusher : https://github.com/ammezie/laravel-chat

Comment: @KinnariPrajapati try my answer, you just need to copy and paste. it is a tested code. you don't need extra package

Comment: yes i am trying that one @rkj

Comment: @rkj I am really confused where to paste your code because i am trying with package and paste also link.. if you help me then i can use `your code`.

Comment: @rkj this is the `package` i am using https://pusher.com/tutorials/chat-laravel/#creating-the-chat-app-view

Comment: no need to use any other package, create a folder `App\Events` and inside this create these 2 files

Comment: @rkj ok i am going to follow you.

Comment: check the namespace of both file, it has `App\Events`

Comment: @rkj what about db ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173499/discussion-between-rkj-and-kinnari-prajapati).

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Create Event Abstract class

```
namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

abstract class Event implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use SerializesModels;

    protected $message;
    protected $channels = [];
    protected $event = '';

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should be broadcast on.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return $this->channels;
    }

    /**
     * Broadcast to event
     */
    public function broadcastAs()
    {
        return $this->event;
    }

    /**
     * Broadcast with message
     */
    public function broadcastWith()
    {
        return  $this->message;
    }
}
```

> Now Create PusherEvent Class

```
namespace App\Events;

class PusherEvent extends Event
{

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     * @param $message
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setMessage($message)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set pusher channels
     */
    public function setChannels($channels)
    {
        $this->channels = $channels;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set pusher event
     */
    public function setEvent($event)
    {
        $this->event = $event;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

> Now Broadcast from anywhere at Laravel Side like this

```
    try {
            $messageEvent = new PusherEvent();
            $messageEvent->setEvent('chatMessage')
                        ->setChannels(['customerChat']);
            $params['message'] = "Hello From Laravel";
            event($messageEvent->setMessage($params));
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            customLog($e->getMessage());
            return false;
        }
```

After calling this code you can check the pusher console. You will get "Hello From Laravel"

It is a working code. I have used in my project. Hope it helps you.

> For listing from js

```
import Echo from "laravel-echo"

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: 'd8649589aa930d275ffe',
    cluster: 'ap2',
    encrypted: true
});

Echo.channel('customerChat')
    .listen('chatMessage', (e) => {
        console.log(e.message);
    });
```

For details https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/broadcasting#concept-overview